# Extracting element from a list in a pandas column based on the value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following pandas df and I would like to extract the element from the list column based on whatever number that is on the num column:

```
list             num
[1,2,3,4,5]       3
[7,2,1,3,4]       4
```

To obtain:

```
list             num    element
[1,2,3,4,5]       3        4
[7,2,1,3,4]       4        4
```

I have tried:

```
df['element'] = df['list'].apply(lambda x: x[df['num'].apply(lambda y: y)])
```

But I got `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series`.

Is there anyway I can do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) per rows with `axis=1`:

```
df['element'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['list'][x['num']], axis=1)
print (df)
              list  num  element
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    3        4
1  [7, 2, 1, 3, 4]    4        4
```

Or list comprehension with `zip`:

```
df['element'] = [x[y]  for x, y in zip(df['list'], df['num'])]
```

If possible some values not match of list, here is possible use:

```
def func(a, b):
    try:
        return a[b]
    except Exception:
        return np.nan    

df['element'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x['list'], x['num']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy fancy index

```
list_val = np.array(df.list.values.tolist())
num_val = df.num.values
df['element'] = list_val[np.arange(df.shape[0]), num_val]

Out[295]:
              list  num  element
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    3        4
1  [7, 2, 1, 3, 4]    4        4
```